# Best way to mock $http promise in this scenario

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

I have a factory function that directly returns the http promise (its about 3 layers deep, and i'm not at all concerned about the path and what is returned)

It looks like this:

```
user.create()
    .success(function(result){})
    .error(function(err){})
```

I just want to mock the success and error bits. I have tried using $q and resolving or rejecting it, but that doesn't seem to work with success and error.

My mock factory with q looks like:

```
var user = {
    create: function (email) {
        var deferred = q.defer();
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
```

And is pretty much what I want to use. Is there a way q can return success and error instead of then?

---

This works so that the code will execute (I based it off the $http source code) but not sure how to test the logic with it

```
var factory = {
        factoryFunction: function () {
            var deferred = q.defer();

            //You can test that it was called here
            deferred.resolve();

            var promise = deferred.promise;
            promise.success = function (fn) {
                //Both success and error get called... be careful
                return promise;
            };

            promise.error = function (fn) {
                //Both success and error get called... be careful
                return promise;
            };
            return promise;
        }
    };
```

Comment: We never need to return a promise from factory. Can you tell the scenario, as in the reason you are taking this approach? What do you want the factory to do exactly?

Comment: @manasisakhare that is plain wrong. Of course services return promises.

Comment: I would refactor the calling code and consider the returned promise as a regular promise rather than a HTTP promise. Note that $q has a `.when()` method that returns a resolved promise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jasmine to run tests against this you can use spyOn.

spyOn(factory, 'create').andCallFake(function () {
    return $.Deferred().resolve({
        ReturnObject: true
    });
});

this website has a great list on how to use spyOn: http://tobyho.com/2011/12/15/jasmine-spy-cheatsheet/